# Got error message in Intellij with android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity clashes onStop

Tags: android, android-fragments, intellij-idea

I 've got a strange behaviour in my Android project. I use Google Maps and fragments. For older versions I use the `support.v4 lib`. Everythng works fine. I can build and run my app.
But my Intellij IDEA 13 shows me a strange error you can see on the picture.
Every `Activity` that use `fragments` is marked as broken.

Can someone help me, that its look normal. 2h ago everything was normal.
I dont know what I have done to create this behaviour.

[image: error in Intellij IDEA 13]

Comment: Hi @BHuelse, did you ever get this issue resolved?

Comment: Hi @KvnH, I still have this problem. I think there is a problem, cause I used support.v4.lib and support.v13.lib. I just use the v13 now and i removed the v4. But the problem is still there.